# Modify Users via Exchange Online REST Api

Tags: powershell, azure, exchangewebservices, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that can modify Exchange Online users via Exchange Online REST API. I need to set Title, City, Department and Manager fields via the API. According to exchange online documentation a contact object has all required fields that I'd like to set. However it looks like the API does not allow me to do changes on user lever. That's a bit confusing.

If I try to access Users endpoint I got error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

However I set all permission for the application in Azure Active Directory.

Here is script that I use:

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll";
 
$clientId = "<<Application Client ID>>";
$certFileFullName = "<<Path to certificate file>>";
$certFilePassword = "<<Password to certificate file>>";
$tenantId = "<<Tenant ID>>";
 
$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/authorize", $false);
 
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 ($certFileFullName, $certFilePassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::MachineKeySet);
$clientAssertionCertificate = new-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate($clientId, $cert);
 
$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", $clientAssertionCertificate);
    
$token = $authenticationResult.AccessToken;
 
$headers = @{ 
    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);
    "User-Agent" = "SyncTool/0.1PowerShell";
    "client-request-id" = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
    "Date" = Get-Date -Format r;
    "Accept" = "application/json";
}
 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users" -Headers $headers;
```

Did someone do that via Exchange Online REST API? Is it even possible?

How should I develop a daemon application that uses App-Only AAD authentication to manager Exchange Online users?

-Dmitry

Comment: For one, PowerShell does not require semicolons at the end of every line, so you can clean up your code in that regard first.  The only place you need semicolons is in your hashtable ($headers @{...})

Comment: I found that MS has released some new API documentation.  Have you looked at it?  Some of your code seems reminiscent of the old way of doing things, which totally was a pain in the keyboard.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#AssignUsersManager

Comment: I don't know if  you're aware, but there is an Azure AD Module you can use for these operations.  That reduces this whole process down to four or five lines of code, and eliminates the need for REST entirely.

Comment: 1. I like semicolons at the end of statements in powershell and SQL, even these are not required.
2. Graph api does not have Application Permissions, only delegated permissions
3. I'm aware about Azure AD Module, but this requires new co-admin added to system and it is not App-Only authentication via AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way to attack this problem the easy method, using the PowerShell module.  Since you already have access to a great and fully featured PowerShell tool, there's really no reason to do this by hand with a REST API, in my experience.

## Using the MSONline Module

We can do everything you need to do except set the manager by using this module

- First, install the MSOnline Module.
- Next, replace the info on line 3 and 4 with your own credentials.

  ```
  import-module MSOnline

  $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'P@ssw0rdHer3!' -AsPlainText -Force
  $credGuest = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('testest@sred13gmail.onmicrosoft.com', $secpasswd)


  connect-msolservice -credential $credGuest

  Get-MsolUser | ? DisplayName -eq 'JSamson' | 
   Set-MsolUser -Department 'Ham Research Team' -Title "Lead Pork Architect" -City "Hamburg"

  Get-MsolUser | ? DisplayName -eq 'JSamson' | Select *Name,Title,City,Depar* | fl 



  DisplayName       : JSamson
  FirstName         : Joe
  LastName          : Sampson
  SignInName        : JoeSampson@sred13gmail.onmicrosoft.com
  UserPrincipalName : JoeSampson@sred13gmail.onmicrosoft.com
  Title             : Lead Pork Architect
  City              : Hamburg
  Department        : Ham Research Team
  ```

## Setting the manager attribute

It turns out the manager attribute isn't accessible from this module.  No idea why that's the case though.  I'm working on a solution for this piece for you, and will update this answer when I've got it finished.

---

## When there's no road, make your own

Integrating some wonderful tips found on this blog post http://goodworkaround.com/node/73 by Marius Solbakken Mellum, we had the basis to connect to Azure AD.  Next, using the wonderful API provided in the Azure AD Graph DLL (you can get it using the nuget command of '.\nuget.exe install Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' and the Azure AD Rest API Reference guide, this set of functions was built.

This tool contains a number of worker functions, such as Get-MSOLGraphUser and Get-MsSOLGraphUserManager.  They are primarily designed to be used by the Set-MSOLGraphUserManager cmdlet itself, but you can feel free to modify and use them to your hearts content.

[New versions of this project will live in GitHub at this url](https://github.com/1RedOne/AzureAD)

Example :

```
Set-MSOLGraphUserManager -targetUser Test -targetManager Stephen
>Successfully found user to modify PSTest
>Successfully looked up manager Stephen Owen
>Updating the manager
>Verifying manager now set for PSTest
>Getting user manager
>PSTest's manager is now Stephen Owen
```

Comment: Thanks, Fox. That approach is fine, however not ideal:
1. With MSOL module you can't change manager. There is no such field. To change manager you should use Exchange Online remote module.
2. I don't want to use my personal credential in PowerShell script on remote server. By security best practices I need to create special user with limited permissions. And in azure I can't do that to a User, but can do with AD application.

Might be that using resource scoped permissions help with that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Alright, I've finished my unified manager setting approach, complete with a handful of new Functions for you to use.  I'll update my post.  For more information, check this blog post: http://goodworkaround.com/node/73

Comment: Also, if you just want to download the cmdlets, here they are :https://github.com/1RedOne/AzureAD

Comment: Thanks, Fox. Great job.

Comment: We already have a pull request on the code too!  Very cool to see people pull together to help flesh out a cmdlet like that, and so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

You should [Office 365 unified API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-reference) which is in public preview to enumerate or modify user information in Azure Active Directory.  This API is in Public Preview, and we are working actively to get it to GA.  In the meantime, if you need to configure users in a production setting, please [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974483.aspx).  These are the supported endpoints for managing user info in directory.  The endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/api lets you specify which user's mailbox you want to access, but doesn't permit you to enumerate users as that is a directory function.

Comment: The unified API does not support App-Only Authentication, does it?